# Find word and return whole line in a full text via MySQL

Tags: mysql, search

I'm going to design a search web script on my content site.

for example this is a text content in The mysql DB.

> A senior U.S. State Department official said Yanukovych had left Kiev
>   for Ukraine's second's largest city of Kharkiv for a meeting after
>   Friday's peace agreement. The official, who spoke on condition of
>   anonymity, had been on the phone with Ukraine's foreign minister.

I search "Kharkiv"
so i wana get this result:

> ...largest city of **Kharkiv** for a meeting after...

what is the best method to do this?

I tried this:

```
<?php
         $_string="Kharkiv";
         $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = "SELECT CONCAT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTR(introtext,1,INSTR(introtext, ".$_string.") - 1)),' ',4)),
                             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(introtext,INSTR(introtext, ".$_string.")),' ',4))
       FROM #__items
       WHERE introtext LIKE '%".$_string."%'
        ";

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
         foreach ($rows as $item) {
          echo $item->introtext;
                } 
           ?>
```

The introtext is a field of item table.

Comment: the best method is try to solve the problem yourself and then ask question, have you tried anything ?

Comment: and please explain a little more about what you want, do you want the exact word ? or **n** char before and after the word, or **x** word before and after it ...

Comment: tnx. I know how to use the like commond .... but I do  not any idia for do this. i want to do this by sql not by php functions...is it possible?....a want get back that word with n words before and after the searched word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
           REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                REVERSE(SUBSTR(
                    text,
                    1,
                    INSTR(text, 'Kharkiv') - 1
                )),
                ' ',
                4
           )),
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTR(
                    text,
                    INSTR(text, 'Kharkiv')
                ),
                ' ',
                4
            )
        )
FROM table_name
WHERE text LIKE '%Kharkiv%'
```

Where `4` is the number of words you need.

Comment: tnx for answer. I tried convert your code to use in php (for jooma3) ,,,but it seems something is wrong...can u guide me more?

Comment: just this: 0 - SQL=SELECT CONCAT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTR(introtext,1,INSTR(introtext, Kharkiv) - 1)),' ',4)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(introtext,INSTR(introtext, Kharkiv)),' ',4)) FROM dnmtr_items WHERE introtext LIKE '%Kharkiv%'

Comment: Please add `print_r($rows);` after `$rows = $db->loadObjectList();` and let me know of the output.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of the print_r($rows)?

Comment: there is not any output...I just got these error: 0 - SQL=SELECT CONCAT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTR(introtext,1,INSTR(introtext, Kharkiv) - 1)),' ',4)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(introtext,INSTR(introtext, Kharkiv)),' ',4)) FROM dnmtr_items WHERE introtext LIKE '%Kharkiv%' ....not anything else

Comment: I believe you missed the quotes around `Kharkiv`. You have two references to `Kharkiv` that are not enclosed in quotes. Change `INSTR(introtext, Kharkiv)` to `INSTR(introtext, 'Kharkiv')`.

Comment: tnx for your answers. :) yes the reason of eeror was quotes. but it dose not work well..so I do it by php functions...thanks anyway :)